# Why isn't my code adding a number with the input field (HTML/Javascript - Beginner)?

Tags: javascript, html

for practice as a beginner I am trying to take a number from a text field, have the user press a button that adds 2 to that number, and then displays it through HTML. However, for some reason I keep getting NaN when applying the code below.

```js
//Setup
var num1 = document.querySelector(".input-box").value;
var btn = document.querySelector(".btn");
//Add
var sum = parseInt(num1) + 2;

btn.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
 e.preventDefault();
 document.querySelector("#output").innerHTML = sum;
})
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Calculate</title>
        <style>

        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="sign">
            <h1>Calculate</h1>
            <form>
                <input type="text" class="input-box" placeholder="Enter Number">
                <input class="btn" type="button" value="Add 2">
            </form>
            <h1 id="output"></h1>
        </div>

        <script src="manip3.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `parseInt('') + 2` is `NaN`. You merely calculate `sum` once when the script gets loaded and not really on click.

Comment: Move your add functionality inside the event listener and also check if `parseInt(value) !== NaN` before adding 2.

Answer (score 2):

You need to move the `num1` and `sum` the inside the event listener

```js
//Setup

var btn = document.querySelector(".btn");
//Add


btn.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
 e.preventDefault();
 // get the number
 var num1 = document.querySelector(".input-box").value;
 // add 2
 var sum = parseInt(num1) + 2;
 document.querySelector("#output").innerHTML = sum;
})
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Calculate</title>
        <style>

        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="sign">
            <h1>Calculate</h1>
            <form>
                <input type="text" class="input-box" placeholder="Enter Number">
                <input class="btn" type="button" value="Add 2">
            </form>
            <h1 id="output"></h1>
        </div>

        <script src="manip3.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to calculate the sum inside the click function. Right now it is calculating before the butten is clicked, when the page loads, which means the input is empty.

Answer (score 1):

as mentioned above you need to resolve after the button is clicked. you could change your variables to function variables.

```
//Setup
 var num1 = function() {return document.querySelector(".input-box").value};
 var btn = document.querySelector(".btn");
//Add
 var sum = function() {return parseInt(num1()) + 2};


btn.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
   e.preventDefault();
   document.querySelector("#output").innerHTML = sum();
 })
```

Answer (score 0):

make the input type = number for better validation

make the button type = submit cause this is form and you need to submit

add submit event to the form cause you can't prevent default without submit event

select input inside the event and convert its value to number by adding + before it

```js
// select from
var form = document.getElementById("form");

form.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    // select input and convert its value to number
    var num1 = +document.querySelector(".input-box").value;
    document.querySelector("#output").innerHTML = num1 + 2;
    // wipe out form after submit
    form.reset();
});
```

```html
<div class="sign">
    <h1>Calculate</h1>
    <form id="form">
        <input type="number" class="input-box" placeholder="Enter Number">
        <input class="btn" type="submit" value="Add 2">
    </form>
    <h1 id="output"></h1>
</div>
```